# On the complexity of global fields isomorphism

Tags: number-fields, function-fields, global-fields

Let $L$ and $K$ be isomorphic global fields (i.e. either function fields of curves over a finite field, or number fields). What is the complexity of finding an isomorphism between them? Is there a polynomial time algorithm?
Notice that the assumption is that $L$ and $K$ are isomorphic simply as fields.

Comment: How is each field given to us? Are we, say, given a polynomial $p \in k[x]$ and the field is defined as $k[x]/(p)$, where $k$ is either $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p(t)$? Or some other way?

Comment: Yes, I would say that this is the most natural input

Comment: I don't know about the complexity, but I can at least point out that finding an isomorphism from $k[y]/(Q)$ to $k[x]/(P)$ is the same as finding a *Tschirnhaus transformation* from $P$ to $Q$. Furthermore, this can be algorithmically tested, at least in theory, by embedding them in the decomposition field of $PQ$, computing the Galois group $G$ of the latter, and checking whether the associated subgroups are conjugate in $G$: so at least it's decidable.

Comment: In Henri Cohen's book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory* (1993, Springer GTM **138**), §4.5 is devoted to this problem (in a slightly more general form, the “subfield problem”). No complexity analysis is given, however.

Comment: This reduces to factorisation of polynomials (in fact roots are enough), so it can be solved in polynomial time.